# How mysql run the query when I use IN operation

Tags: mysql, sql

```
explain 
SELECT Fuid 
FROM profile_industry 
WHERE Findustry_id IN (101,102)
```

[image]

```
explain 
SELECT Fuid 
FROM profile_industry 
WHERE Findustry_id IN (1001,2012)
```

[image]

`Findustry_id` is a single index column,why MySQL use different index where the in value list is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-other-changes-statistics-estimation.html):

> The MySQL query optimizer uses estimated statistics about key
>   distributions to choose the indexes for an execution plan, based on
>   the relative selectivity of the index.

My guess is that the keys in the second select many rows, but in the first select few rows -- at least according to the statistics supported by the index.  If a large'ish percentage of rows are chosen (10%?  20%? 50%?), then a full table scan is more efficient than using an index.

Comment: I think so too. I checked that Findustry_id  with value 2012 is much more than others, so mysql use all table query to use Sequence IO
rather than random IO.